# Jackson @JsonIgnore property is null

Tags: java, json, jackson

I want convert json string to one object.

The json looks like this:

```
{"receive":1413342268310}
```

And the object is like:

```
public class PositionBean {  
    private Long id;
    private Date receive;

    public void setReceive (Date receive) {
        this.receive = receive;
    }

    public void setReceive (Long receive) {
        this.receive = new Date (receive);
    }

    public Long getReceive () {
        return receive.getTime ();
    }
}
```

All the set and get methods I have to use in other class, so I can't delete one method.
When I invoke

```
objectMapper.readValue(str, PositionBean.class);
```

It prompt exception, the jackon don't know which method set, so I use @JsonIgnore, but I found the receive is null.

Comment: Your best approach is probably to write a custom deserializer which converts a `long` to a `Date`. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158345/custom-json-deserialization-with-jackson) might be useful. (I'm sure someone has an example of this exact case out there; Jackson might even include such a mapper by default.)

Comment: Where do You use the @jsonignore? On the method? If so, could You try to do it on the receive field?

Comment: Could u update the could on where u have used JSONIgnore annotation??

Comment: please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308452/how-to-convert-the-following-json-string-to-java-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use annotation [**@JsonSetter**](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.3.4/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonSetter.html) to specify which method should be used as setter.

**Example:**

```
public class PositionBean {  
    private Long id;
    private Date receive;

    public void setReceive (Date receive) {
        this.receive = receive;
    }

    @JsonSetter
    public void setReceive (Long receive) {
        this.receive = new Date (receive);
    }

    public Long getReceive () {
        return receive.getTime ();
    }
}
```

When you mark setter (e.g. *setXXX*) with [**@JsonIgnore**](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.3.4/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonIgnore.html) it means that property *XXX* will be ignored.
From documentation:

> For example, a "getter" method that would otherwise denote a property
>   (like, say, "getValue" to suggest property "value") to serialize,
>   would be ignored and no such property would be output unless another
>   annotation defines alternative method to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

This will not throw any mapping exception even if u dont have an appropriate field in the mapping class corresponding to a JSON field. Once configured u can use ur code for further processing.

```
objectMapper.readValue (str, PositionBean.class);
```