# How to parse date with optional characters in format

Tags: java, date, jackson, jodatime

I have the following two dates:

- 8 Oct. 2009
- 13 May 2010

I am using Jackson to convert the date from an rest api to joda Datetime.

I thought the pattern `"dd MMM. yyyy"` would work but the "may" has no dot so it crashes at that point.

Is there a solution or do I have to write my own datetime parser?

The annotation in jackson is:

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "dd MMM. yyyy", timezone = "UTC", locale = "US", )
@JsonProperty(value = "date")
private DateTime date;
```

So there is only one date pattern allowed.

Comment: Cant you just add the dot if the month is may?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given OP's new comment and requirements, the solution is to use a custom deserializer:

You would do something like this:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = MyDateDeserializer.class)
class MyClassThatHasDateField {...}
```

See tutorial here: http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization

See an example here: [Custom JSON Deserialization with Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158345/custom-json-deserialization-with-jackson)

**OLD ANSWER:**

You can use Java's `SimpleDateFormat` and either:

1. Use a regex to choose the proper pattern
2. Simply try them and catch (and ignore) the exception

Example:

```
String[] formats = { "dd MMM. yyyy", "dd MM yyyy" };

for (String format : formats)
{
    try
    {
        return new SimpleDateFormat( format ).parse( theDateString );
    }
    catch (ParseException e) {}
}
```

OR

```
String[] formats = { "dd MMM. yyyy", "dd MM yyyy" };
String[] patterns = { "\\d+ [a-zA-Z]+\. \d{4}", "\\d+ [a-zA-Z]+ \d{4}" };

for ( int i = 0; i < patterns.length; i++ )
{
  // Create a Pattern object
  Pattern r = Pattern.compile(patterns[ i ] );

  // Now create matcher object.
  Matcher m = r.matcher( theDateString );

  if (m.find( )) {
     return new SimpleDateFormat( formats[ i ] ).parse( theDateString );
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that i this date comes from an rest service and i parse it 
automatically and in the jackson annotation jsonformat allows only one pattern. in normal source code the above problem would be easy to solve

Answer (score 0):

You could just define two formatters and use the one with a dot, if it is present in the string.

```
String dateString = "8 Oct. 2009";

DateTimeFormatter formatWithDot    = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd MMM. yyyy");
DateTimeFormatter formatWithoutDot = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd MMM yyyy");

DateTime date = dateString.indexOf('.') > -1
    ? formatWithDot.parseDateTime(dateString)
    : formatWithoutDot.parseDateTime(dateString);
```

Answer (score 0):

There would also be a different way by fixing the string for parsing:

```
String date = "13 May. 2009";
DateTime result = DateTime.parse(date.replace(".",""),
DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd MMM yyyy"));
```