# How to construct case-insensitive enum using Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I want to have all my enum objects capitalized. how to make it case-insensitive?

HTTP body to `JsonNode` and then node to a class object:

```
JsonNode asJson = request().body().asJson();
WhatsappIncomingMessageVO requestVO = JsonParserUtils.fromJson(asJson, WhatsappIncomingMessageVO.class);
```

The JSON has the lowercase string "location" which I want to map with the LOCATION of the below enum
the class contains one enum which is :

```
public enum WhatsAppMessageType {

    TEMPLATE("TEMPLATE"),
    TEXT("TEXT"),
    IMAGE("image"), 
    VIDEO("video"), 
    AUDIO("audio"),
    @JsonProperty("json")
    LOCATION("location");
```

Answer (score 12):

If you are using [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)... and I think yes, there are multiple solutions

#### 1. Use an annotation with your @JsonProperty:

```java
@JsonAlias({"location", "LOCATION", "Location"})
```

#### 2. Write custom JsonDeserializer:

With the `JsonDeserializer` you can [implement any logic you want](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19167145/155248).

#### 3. Use the @JsonFormat [annotation](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.html) for your field:

```java
@JsonFormat(with = JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES)
```

#### 4. Set the format programmatically for all fields:

```java
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_ENUMS, true);
```

This is what you need if you want enum values to be case insensitive.