# How to write custom JSON Deserializer for Jackson?

Tags: java, jackson

I need to deserialize some JSON to Java class. I have the following JSON:

```
{
  "list": [[{
        "type": "text",
        "subType": "ss"
     },
     {
        "type": "image",
        "subType": "text"
     }
]]
}
```

and I have the following Java classes:

```
public abstract class BaseClass {
    public String type;
    public String subType;
}

public class Text extends BaseClass {
   ...
}

public class Image extends BaseClass {
}
```

and I need deserialize in this way, if `type` equals `image` and `subType` equals `text` I need to deserialize into `Text` class otherwise I need deserialize to `Image` class.

How can I do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom JSON Deserialization with Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158345/custom-json-deserialization-with-jackson)

Comment: @Héctor Thanks, but this approach not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a custom deserializer. Mark your BaseClass with the following annotations, and deserialize with an ObjectMapper:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "type", visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes({@JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Text.class, name = "text"), @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Image.class, name = "image")
})
public abstract class BaseClass {
    public String type;
    public String subType;
}
```

`JsonTypeInfo` defines to use value of `type` field for type name.
`JsonSubTypes` associates type names with java classes

Comment: Yes, but I need to do something like this: I have one abstract class, for instance, ```BaseClass``` and three subclasses which extends ```BaseClass```, ```MyClass1```, ```MyClass2``` and ```MyClass3```. I need to deserialize my JSON to ```MyClass1``` if type equals text and subtype equals image and instantiates ```MyClass 2``` if type equals text and subtype equal text and instantiate ```MyClass3``` if type equals image and not does it matter what is subtype equals.

Comment: So you want to use two properties to select a Subtype. As far as I know it has not been implemented in Jackson. You should implement a custom deserializer, like the other answer describes.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own deserializer like so:

```
public class BaseClassDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<BaseClass> { 

    public BaseClassDeserializer(Class<?> vc) { 
        super(vc); 
    }

    @Override
    public BaseClass deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) 
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
        String type = node.get("type").asText();
        String subType = node.get("subType").asText();

        if("image".equals(type) && "text".equals(subType)){
            /* create Text class
            return new Text */
        } else {
            /* create Image class
            return new Image(args...) */
        }
    }
}
```