# DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_IGNORED_PROPERTIES as annotation

Tags: java, jackson, json-deserialization

I use jackson library and I have @JsonPOJOBuilder class for deserialize JSON. I added @JsonIgnoreProperties for ignore some fields. For example:

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@SuperBuilder
@JsonDeserialize(builder = SubClass.BuilderImpl.class)
public class SubClass extends MainClass {

    @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"a1", "a2"})
    static final class BuilderImpl
            extends builder<SubClass, BuilderImpl> {
    }

    public SubClass() {
        super();
    }
}
```

I need get throw when json with some of ignored field, such as

```
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_IGNORED_PROPERTIES, true);
```

How can I do this with annotation or, maybe, exist other variant do this in SubClass?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you want to throw an exception when there is any unknown field in json other than ignored fields?

Comment: @Smile, Yes, i want to throw an exception when there is any unknown fields or ignored fields.

Comment: Did you try `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = false)`? (Though I think this is the default behaviour)

Comment: @Smile, yes, but it didn't help :(
Unknown fields throwed an exception, but ignored fields was without exception.

Comment: Why do you want to throw exception on ignored fields? What's the use case?

Comment: @Smile,  I need for ignored fields same behavior, such as with unknown fields. It is task requirement.

Comment: You can possibly look at custom deserializer

Comment: @Smile. Thans a lot for answer) Do you mean use ObjectMapper?

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/19167145/1776132