# Jackson does include object with nested null values which shouldn't

Tags: java, jackson

I don't want to include nested objects values in `json` which are `null`, but I obtain different result. I have class:

```
@Data
public class HoldsType {

    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    protected HoldTypeIndicatorType holdTypeIndicator;
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    protected HoldReasonsType holdReasons;
}
```

And it contains nested `HoldTypeIndicatorType` class:

```
@Data
public class HoldTypeIndicatorType {

    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    protected Boolean dealerAssignment;
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    protected Boolean someSpecification;
}
```

I added there @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL) annotations to exclude those fields from results json, but I receive:

```
{
 "holdTypeIndicator": {}
}
```

I tried also adding

- NON_DEFAULT property, or
- NON_ABSETNT property,
  but it's the same.

The problem is here I have tons of fields type: `Boolean`.
What should be the simplest way to add this behavior to `ObjectMapper` to not include this `holdTypeIndicator` object, when all `Boolean` nested values are null, in `json`?
Writing custom Serializable will require adding annotation to all of those fields. Is there any way I can override `ObjectMapper` default serializer for this?

Comment: If my understanding is correct and you do not want to include holdTypeIndicator at all, if any of its subfields are null, then perhaps you need to write a custom Deserializer.
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158345/custom-json-deserialization-with-jackson

Comment: @SusanMustafa I know I can, but may be there is also another way to override ObjectMapper default serializer?

Comment: You can add `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` at the class level instead of the field level. You don't have to add it to each individual field.