# Dropwizard conf file automatically convert value to custom object

Tags: java, dropwizard

I have a dropwizard application that parses conf files to construct the application's configuration.

base.conf file has:

```
country: USA
```

in the configuration java file:

```
@NotNull
private MyObject country;
```

MyObject is not an enum in this case. It is a regular object.

How can I configure it to have dropwizard automatically convert the parsed string value to MyObject based on some logic I define, like:

```
MyObject convertStringToMyObject(String value) {
    if (value.equals("USA") {
        return new MyObject("+1", "North America", "USA");
    }
}
```

This is obviously just the simplest dumb sample I could think of for what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Dropwizard uses Jackson, right? You should be able to add a custom deserializer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19167145/8681

Comment: that's a good start, but the problem is that MyObject is a class in a library i dont own

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of different ways you might want to consider when approaching:

(1) Use an enumeration in the configuration and then provide a mapping to the `MyObject` class which controls the instantiation of the fields driven by the country. This will make it clear which countries are supported (and for which you have mappings).

```
public class MyConfig extends Configuration {

    enum Country {
        USA;

        MyObject toObject() {
            switch (this) {
                case USA:
                    return new MyObject("+1", "North America"...);
            }
            ...
        }
    }
    
    public Country country;
}
```

(2) Register a custom deserialiser. Even if you don't own the `MyObject` class you will still be able to register a custom deserialiser either directly on the `ObjectMapper` or by using the `JsonDeserializer(using = MyObjectDeserializer)` annotation on the field in your application configuration (rather than on the `MyObject` class declaration which as you say - is not editable by you) - example:

```
public class MyConfig extends Configuration {

    @JsonDeserialize(using = MyObjectDeserializer.class)
    public MyObject country;
}
```